# how to find out many levels opened?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I use angularjs. view item with it's subItems and it's subItems etc.
when I click on e.g. level 1-1, I want to find out how many sublevels are opened.How to do it?

[image]

Here is the html code:

**main level**

```
 <div>
    <div ng-repeat="level in vm.levels track by $index"  >
        <div  layout="row" >
            <div class="padding-left-20">
                <md-icon style="font-size:16px;" aria-hidden="true" class=" ng-scope md-cyan-theme material-icons zmdi zmdi-plus-circle-o" ng-click="vm.createChild(level)></md-icon>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span  class="capitalize">{{level.name)}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="end end"  flex="10" ng-click="vm.shouldShowChildren[$index]=!vm.shouldShowChildren[$index]>
                <div>
                    <md-icon class=" menu-toggle-icon"  style="font-size:20px;" md-font-icon="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right" ng-class="{ open: vm.shouldShowChildren[$index] }"></md-icon>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="vm.shouldShowChildren[$index]" class="collapseChildren" dragula="'folder-bag'">
            <div ng-repeat="child in level.children track by child.id"   ng-include="'app/level-child.tmpl.html' "></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**level-child.tmpl.html**

```
 <div layout="row"  class=" btn hoverChildIteration padding-left-40" id={{child.id}} ng-init="vm.dragContainerId = child.id" >
  <div class="padding-left-30 ">
    <md-icon style="font-size:16px;" id={{child.id}}icon aria-hidden="true" class=" ng-scope md-cyan-theme material-icons zmdi zmdi-plus-circle-o" title="add sub folder" ></md-icon>
  </div>
<div class="names" flex >
    <span class="capitalize">{{child.name)}}</span>
</div>
<div layout="row" layout-align="end end"  flex="10" ng-click="showGrandChildren[child.id]=!showGrandChildren[child.id]">
    <div >
        <md-icon class="menu-toggle-icon" id={{child.id}}chevron style="font-size:20px;" md-font-icon="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right"  ng-class="{ open: showGrandChildren[child.id] }"></md-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Solved issue**

I have next level DOM element.So I just check if it exists, and if it's true - I just send its children to check if there exist.If yes - level++

```
    <div ng-if="vm.shouldShowChildren[$index]" class="collapseChildren" dragula="'folder-bag'">
        <div ng-repeat="child in level.children track by child.id"   ng-include="'app/level-child.tmpl.html' "></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What plugin is this ? They should have an inbuilt method to help you out

Comment: no plugin. just angulajs and angular material

Comment: Solved.Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.Updated my question with Solved*

Comment: You can add solution in answer section and mark as answer.